# simplifying rationals

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Hi I was looking at this problem and I forgot a little on how to simplify rational expressions. It's

$\frac{x^4-8x}{3x^3-2x^2-8}$

I know I can pull out an x from that top and get $x(x^3-8)$ but I'm not sure about the bottom. Can this problem even be simplified?

Comment: $a^3-b^3 = (a-b)(a^2+ab+b^2)$ this may help when trying to factorize the denominator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It largely depends on your definition of "simplified."  One strategy in simplifying rational functions is to write the polynomial in the numerator as a product of linear polynomials and do the same to the bottom.  I.e., try to get it in the form $\frac{(x-\alpha_1)(x-\alpha_2)\dots(x-\alpha_m)}{(x-\beta_1)(x-\beta_2)\dots(x-\beta_n)}$

Looking at the top, we have $x^4-8x$.  As you correctly note, you can pull out an $x$, leaving us with $x(x^3-8)$.  By inspection, $2$ is also a root.  Through synthetic division, you see that it is $x(x-2)(x^2+2x+4)$.  By the quadratic formula we can finish factoring, and so the top can be seen to be $x(x-2)(x+1+i\sqrt{3})(x+1-i\sqrt{3})$

As for the bottom of the expression, it is not easily factorable.  The most sure method would be to use [the cubic formula](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CubicFormula.html) which is not recommended to a precalculus student.  The cubic formula is similar to the quadratic formula you learned in that it can tell you exactly what the roots of a cubic polynomial are.  As a side-note, there exists also a formula for quartic equations which is even uglier, but it was proven by Galois that there cannot exist a closed form solution to quintic or higher degree polynomials (using $\sqrt[\bullet]{~},\times,+,/$)

The next best bet would be [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=factor%203x%5E3-2x%5E2-8) to see if the denominator can be factored easily, which shows that it cannot.  The denominator is approximately $3(x-1.648)(x+0.4908+1.1735i)(x+0.4908-1.1735i)$.

As a result, our function looks like $\frac{x(x-2)(x+1+i\sqrt{3})(x+1-i\sqrt{3})}{3(x-1.648)(x+0.4908+1.1735i)(x+0.4908-1.1735i)}$ and we see that we cannot cancel any linear factors from top and bottom.

Answer (score 1):

It would help if we knew exactly what you were trying to accomplish by the simplification. There's nothing that "obvious" that can be done here (other than what you mentioned). One way to get to another form is to do polynomial long division. This yields:

$$\frac 19 [3x + 2 + \frac{4(x^2 - 12x + 4)}{3x^3 - 2x^2 - 8}]$$

From this point on, it's difficult to proceed unless you give a clearer idea of your goal. Neither the quadratic numerator nor the cubic denominator in the second term has a rational factorisation. But this form is still useful, for example if you were integrating the expression.

Answer (score 0):

Since non of the denominator's zeroes, namely $0$ and $2$ is a zero of the numerator, simplyfying by cancellation won't work.